# counting increment as a step in a for loop or not

Tags: for-loop

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   // Some code
}
```

We generally say that this loop runs for n+1 times so n+1 steps for this and there is one step is of initialisation i=0.
This I have read in most of the text books.
My question is this that everytime the loop runs there is one more step of incrementing i to i+1 that is i=i+1, this is also one of the step which should be counted in calculating the time complexity.As I am a newbie to algorithm analysis help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We generally say that this loop runs for n+1 times so n+1 steps for this [...]

No, we say it runs for *n* iterations. That's the point in combining a starting index of `0` with the boundary-check written as `< n`. It will exit the loop once the counter reaches `n`, after having taken `n` iterations (one for 0, one for 1, one for 2, ... one for n - 1, then exit).

The work done to increment the counter, be it `i++`, `i += 1` or `i = compute_the_next_index(i)`, does not count as a "step". The steps are the iterations, i.e. the executions of the loop's body.

Comment: My question is this that why we dont count this as a step.
If we write i=i+1 in our main then we count it as 1 step then why here we dont count it as a step.

Comment: What do you mean by "a step"? And when do you "count steps"? Are you talking about "statements", a term often used to describe program text?